Why update trigger is fired on master record when there is no field update after merge dml on master record
I ran this code from dev console
Account masterAcct = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Account1'];
Account mergeAcct = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Account2'];
merge masterAcct mergeAcct;

in mergeAcct Description field has value but in masterAcct the value was blank. I found that related records of mergeAcct got reparented to masterAcct but field values were not
Salesforce documentation states that

Documentation also states that

So basically if field1 has value in master as well as on record to be merged, value of master record takes precedence and wont be overwritten. But what if field value is blank in master as in my case.
Since merge dml fires update trigger on master record, I added some debug statements in trigger to understand it better. Below is the trigger code
trigger accountTrigger on Account(after update) {
  if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
    System.debug('Master record updated successfully');

    Set<String> updatedFields = new Set<String>();
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

    // Loop through all records being updated    
    for (Account newAccount : Trigger.new) {
      Account oldAccount = Trigger.oldMap.get(newAccount.Id);

      // Loop through each field to check if it was updated
      for (String fieldName : fieldMap.keySet()) {
        Object oldValue = oldAccount.get(fieldName);
        Object newValue = newAccount.get(fieldName);

        // Add field to the set if the value has changed
        if (oldValue != newValue) {
          updatedFields.add(fieldName);
        }
      }
      System.debug('Fields updated: ' + updatedFields);
    }
  }
}

The second debug statement prints empty set even though value of description field in master account was blank but has value in the record to be merged. If no field in master record gets updated why update trigger fires for master record? Is it like merge dml just reparents child records of records to be merged to master record and doesn't update any of the field values?

Do you have any Roll-Up Summary fields on account?  Those will also fire the update triggers in a merge.

@David - No I dont have any roll up summary field on account
